# VSphere CLI: how do I take a new Snapshot and add description?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm working on a VSphere CLI script that will take 6 snapshots and allow me to make the description of each snapshot be the date it was created. At the moment here's the code that I'm trying:

```
$server = "<ServerName>"
connect-VIserver $server
$snapshot = Get-vm | New-Snapshot -Name $"<serverName>" | Set-Snapshot -$snapshot -Description get-date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one call

> Get-VM | New-Snapshot -Name "$serverName" -Description (Get-Date)

I'm not sure why you want to do this as, the snapshot object has a property called "Created"
You can get it by doing something like this:

> $snapshots = Get-VM | New-Snapshot -Name "$serverName"
>
> $snapshots | foreach { Set-Snapshot -Description $_.Created }